# JSX onClick keeps evaluating, InternalError: too much recursion

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React.  Could anyone explain to me what the problem is?  It seems that onClick function keeps firing from both buttons resulting in an infinite recursion.

```
export class MyButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { selectedIndex: 0 };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(newIndex) {
        this.setState({
            selectedIndex: newIndex
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick(0)} >Button 0</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick(1)} >Button 1</button>
                <span>{this.state.selectedIndex}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

`this.handleClick(0)` will fire with render, without click, because you call the function.

Then `setState` call new render and call `handleClick` again

`onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}` will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need **to pass** a function **not to call it**

```
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)} >Button 0</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)} >Button 1</button>
            <span>{this.state.selectedIndex}</span>
        </div>
```

Other solution would be to make you `handleClick` to return a function

```
handleClick(newIndex) {
    return () => this.setState({
        selectedIndex: newIndex
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick(0)} >Button 0</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick(1)} >Button 1</button>
            <span>{this.state.selectedIndex}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Also (a more performat approach since it wont create new functions on each render call) could be to keep value in the button itself (yes-yes [`<button>` has value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button))

```
handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
        selectedIndex: +event.target.value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button value="0" onClick={this.handleClick} >Button 0</button>
            <button value="1" onClick={this.handleClick} >Button 1</button>
            <span>{this.state.selectedIndex}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why is there a + in front of event?  (selectedIndex: +event.target.value)

Comment: @Dimskiy You want numbers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}>Button 0</button>
```

Comment: Otherwise the function fires on render instead of on click.  Good luck!